# Remove words from a string based on appearance

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have to remove a word/words in my string for some cases. For example,
My string is `incabcincdefinc inc. inc`. For this I need to remove both `inc.` and `inc`. 
ie, output should be `incabcincdefinc`. 
ie, remove all `inc`s as per the following conditions:

```
<space>inc<space>
<space>inc<.>
<space>inc<end string>
<space>inc
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Also, as a hint, you know what your delimiters are, so you don't need a regex when you can `split` instead.

Comment: 'inc' is an example. Actually I need to remove business entity extensions like inc,ltd,corp etc. from company name.

Comment: Again, `split`, loop through the resulting array, and move on with your life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get away with something like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[ ](?:inc|ltd|corp)\\b\\.?", "");
```

The square brackets are only used to make the space characters in between more visible, they could be omitted, as long as the space is kept. Your conditions are met by asserting that there is a word boundary (`\\b`) after the business entity extension. That means that there is no letter, digit or underscore coming next (which captures all your conditions). Then the pattern also tries to include a literal period (`\\.`), but does not care if there is non (`?`). Everything is replaced with an empty string. Note that in your first condition I do not match and remove the space, because that would make `SomeCompany inc inc` become `SomeCompanyinc`.

If you want to look for the extension case-insensitively, you need to use the longer syntax:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "[ ](?:inc|ltd|corp)\\b\\.?",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
str = matcher.replaceAll("");
```